Font family gets changed when email forwarded to Gmail
When the email forwarded from my MACBook pro outlook to Gmail, the font family gets changed for the texts but this is not the case when email forwarded from Windows device
Please note our Main font is "Inter" but I am expecting at-least Arial font to work in Gmail.
Here is the example
Example one : when font-family: 'Inter', Arial;

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700" rel="stylesheet" />
      <title>Email Font test : Inter</title>
   </head>
   <body id="body" bgcolor="#f5f4f8">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: 'Inter', Arial;color:#54565A;mso-font-alt: 'Arial';">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="text" style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Inter',Arial; mso-font-alt: 'Arial'; font-size:16px;color:#54565A;line-height:22px;">
                  <p style="font-size:22px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy </p>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>


outlook view

Gmail view in Macbook Pro : I guess Times New Roman font applied
Gmail HTML view
Example two : when font-family: 'Source Sans 3', Arial;  working as expected
This is where font family shows as Arial in Gmail.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+3:ital,wght@0,200..900;1,200..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Email Font test :  Source Sans 3</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body" bgcolor="#f5f4f8">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: 'Source Sans 3', Arial;color:#54565A;mso-font-alt: 'Arial';">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text" style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Source Sans 3',Arial; mso-font-alt: 'Arial'; font-size:16px;color:#54565A;line-height:22px;">
                        <p style="font-size:22px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>


Outlook view
Gmail view
